# Fastest C++ Container: Unique Values

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, data-structures, vector

I am writing an email application that interfaces with a MySQL database. I have two tables that are sourcing my data, one of which contains unsubscriptions, the other of which is a standard user table. As of now, I'm creating a vector of pointers to email objects, and storing all of the unsubscribed emails in it, initially. I then have a standard SQL loop in which I'm checking to see if the email is not in the unsubscribe vector, then adding it to the global send email vector. My question, is, is there a more efficient way of doing this? I have to search the unsub vector for every single email in my system, up to 50K different ones. Is there a better structure for searching? And, a better structure for maintaining a unique collection of values? Perhaps one that would simply discard the value if it already contains it?

Comment: DVK and Daniel Trebbien are right: it's almost certainly better to do this in the DB.  I don't believe you when you say this is impossible -- please post the relevant parts of the schema.

Comment: why generating emails prior to checking if the user wishes to receive it ? You're doing extra work here...

Comment: @Matthieu: I'm not generating email content, I'm gathering email addresses to cross reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your C++ Standard Library implementation supports it, consider using a [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)  or a `std::hash_set`.

You can also use `std::set`, though its overhead might be higher (it depends on the cost of generating a hash for the object versus the cost of comparing two of the objects several times).

If you do use a node based container like `set` or `unordered_set`, you also get the advantage that removal of elements is relatively cheap compared to removal from a `vector`.

Comment: I think you mean `std::unordered_set` or `std::tr1::unordered_set`

Comment: Also, `std::hash_set` is not part of the standard, you are better off using `boost::unordered_set` if you don't have either TR1 or c++0x.

Comment: @Evan:  You're right; I meant `std::unordered_set`.  I haven't had coffee this morning.  Most Standard Library implementations provide `hash_set` in one form or another.

Answer (score 5):

1. Tasks like this (set manipulations) are better left to what is MEANT to execute them - the database!

   E.g. something along the lines of:

   ```
    SELECT email FROM all_emails_table e WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM unsubscribed u where e.email=u.email
    )
   ```
2. If you want an ALGORITHM, you can do this fast by retrieving both the list of emails AND a list of unsubscriptions as ORDERED lists. Then you can go through the e-mail list (which is ordered), and as you do it you glide along the unsubscribe list. The idea is that you move 1 forward in whichever list has the "biggest" current" element. This algo is O(M+N) instead of O(M*N) like your current one
3. Or, you can do a hash map which maps from unsubscribed e-mail address to 1. Then you do `find()` calls on that map whcih for correct hash implementations are O(1) for each lookup.
   Unfortunately, there's no Hash Map standard in C++ - please see [this SO question for existing implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055208/c-data-structure-with-lookuptime-o1-like-javas-hashmap-in-stl) (couple of ideas there are SGI's [STL hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash%5Fmap.html) and Boost and/or TR1 `std::tr1::unordered_map`).

   One of the comments on that post indicates it will be added to the standard: "With this in mind, the C++ Standard Library Technical Report introduced the unordered associative containers, which are implemented using hash tables, and they have now been added to the Working Draft of the C++ Standard."

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that for part of my application, due to the way one of the tables was previously laid out.

Comment: @Josh: Would you post the relevant parts of your schema? Do you have a separate table for unsubscribed e-mails?

Comment: Why not use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? `SELECT \`email\` FROM \`all_emails_table\` AS \`e\` LEFT OUTER JOIN \`unsubscribed\` AS \`u\` ON \`e\`.\`email\` = \`u\`.\`email\` WHERE \`u\`.\`email\` IS NULL;`

Comment: @Daniel - I come from TSQL background, so writing anti-joins via `NOT EXISTS` is more natural form me than ANSI SQL's equivalent `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. But the two are pretty much the same (though not always so from performance standpoint - Google for "anti-join performance outer exists" or something like that for several excellent articles for various database servers - I know there are some for MySQL and MS SQL).

Answer (score 4):

Store your email adresses in a `std::set` or use [`std::set_difference()`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_difference.html).

Comment: +1 for `set_difference` (because it's baked in), but I would recommend using 3 (sorted) vectors rather than sets, because it should be faster to traverse them (better memory locality). Alternatively, `deque` could be considered too, if the size is large, and you're not using Dirkumware (and its small buckets).

Comment: @Matthieu: When using `set_difference`, of course you would use sorted vectors.  What else?

Comment: just making sure :) node based containers can be painfully slow.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is within MySQL, I think. You can modify your users table schema with another column, a `BIT` column, for "is unsubscribed". Better yet: add a `DATETIME` column for "date deleted" with a default value of `NULL`.

If using a `BIT` column, your query becomes something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `unsubscribed` <> 0b1;
```

If using a `DATETIME` column, your query becomes something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `date_unsubscribed` IS NULL;
```

Comment: Also, now you're unsubscribing users. The current schema unsubscribes email addresses, which isn't exactly the same thing. If a user changes their email address to one which is unsubscribed, then should they stop receiving messages? OP's approach says "yes", this says "no", which I would guess is more likely to be the right answer.